# Does createCustomToken(aUID) logout users currently authenticated with that same aUID

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

TLDR; Can multiple different users be authenticated and retain authentication via a generated custom token IF that custom token for each of those users is being generated always by the same UID? That is, User1 gets custom token generated by `UID1` (via `createCustomToken(UID1)`) and then signed-in with `signInWithCustomToken()`, THEN User2 gets and signs-in with custom token generated using `UID1`, then User3 same thing etc etc, can ALL these users happily remained logged-in and experience no interruptions despite these other users being authenticated in this identical manner?

Long Version:

Ok, so I am trying to create a link-sharing system wherein a user who navs to this link can access a specific subset of my project's Firebase resources.
I have already tried using Firebase's `signInAnonymously()` to do this, but I dont like the way that Firebase does this for a whole host of reasons I dont want to get into.

The way *i* want to accomplish this is by:

1. generating a unique link (really a Firestore unique doc ID with some access data stored in that doc)
2. having the unauthenticated user navigate to some landing page, calling the cloud function and passing that unique link (lets call it a UID now)
3. cloud function, upon recieving this UID, will `createCustomToken(UID)`, returning the token back to calling user
4. and the user will authenticate themselves with `signInWithCustomToken(returnedToken)` and access provisioned resources

Now, that is all well and good, but my question is:

If two (or any amount more people) people navigate to that same link and therefore pass and create token with the same UID, will they *all* be ok to continue happily using Firebase resources? Or is it because they got tokens created for them which utilised the same UID a sort of token-conflict is made, and therefore any next user who authenticates in this manner will revoke the previous user's auth token.

I havent been able to try this, and it seems like every question asked about these custom tokens relates to the generation and expiry time of them, which I understand. I wish the Auth docs were more clear on the mechnics and pitfalls of using Custom Tokens. I also havent been able to try it myself as it would be quite alot of refactoring, and was hoping someone could give me a straight answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a user can login on multiple devices without affecting other sessions at the same time irrespective of which auth method you use.

I'm not sure what the *unique links* are but it's not a good idea to pass the UID itself around if you function just takes a UID and returns a custom token as UIDs are pretty short and just a random string. It might be best to add a custom signed JWT in the links that contain the UID in payload so you can verify them before creating Firebase Custom Tokens.